# Programmatically discourage constructor initialization?

Tags: c#, constructor, factory, obsolete

I have a class `Foo` and a static class `FooFactory`, which is used to create instances of `Foo` and `Foo` derived classes via the following API:

```
public static class FooFactory {
  public static T Create<T>() where T : Foo, new() { 
    ...
    return new T();
  }
}
```

The `new()` specialization of the `T` type parameter requires `Foo` to have a `public` default constructor. In other words, nothing is preventing a user of `Foo` to initialize the class directly via the constructor.

> However, `FooFactory` is intended to keep track of all `Foo` instances, so I want to enforce the user to create all `Foo` and `Foo` derived instances via the `FooFactory`.

The closest I have been able to prevent direct constructor initialization is to decorate the `Foo` default constructor with the `[Obsolete("message", error: true)]` attribute:

```
public class Foo {      
  [Obsolete("Fail", true)]
  public Foo() { ... }
}
```

With this decoration the code does not compile when I call the `Foo` default constructor directly, whereas initialization via `FooFactory.Create<Foo>()` works.

But with this `[Obsolete]` decoration, I still have problems with derived classes. The following won't even compile due to the `error: true` setting for the `Foo` default constructor:

```
public class Bar : Foo { ... }

public class Baz : Foo { public Baz() : base() { ... } }
```

I can declare a `protected` `Foo` constructor overload that the derived classes invoke instead of the default constructor, but then I will have no ability to programmatically prevent direct initialization of the derived classes.

If I set `error` in the `ObsoleteAttribute` to `false`, I get compilation warnings instead, but I would like to have stronger discouragement than warnings...

*Is there any way that I can programmatically prevent direct invocation of the default constructor for both `Foo` and derived classes when the default constructors are required to be declared `public`?*

Comment: Make the constructor `internal` to the library and remove the `new()` constraint. This now meant that you are responsible for the creation of all Foo types

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the `new()` requirement only works if the constructor is declared `public`.

Comment: You will have to remove the constraint

Comment: That is not an option...

Comment: well that is how the constraint works. You can't get what it is you are requesting.

Comment: When you're in a hole, stop digging. Make the constructor of `Foo` do the instance tracking, through invoking a static field and `this.GetType()`.

Comment: If you have complete control of Foo and derived types, you could make them internal and expose Interfaces they implement. Your Create method could take the interface as a parameter and through reflection  determine which class to instantiate.
However: indoing so, you lose the compile time checking of the parameter type for Create.

Comment: Good point, Jeroen. I initially did this, but removed it when I refactored the class. When re-examining the current source code I see that it could make sense to re-introduce the registration in the constructor. Thanks!

Comment: Great, because as stated, your demands are literally impossible to meet otherwise. In particular, it is impossible to forbid declaring a `Baz` that can be constructed directly -- the author could *always* provide a public constructor for users that bypasses any of your demands, regardless of how `Foo` was set up. If you assume authors are always in cahoots and can assume they'll behave, my second suggestion would have been to drop the `new()` constraint and pass the constructor call as a `Func<T>` to an internal method. This maintains type safety but is cumbersome for authors.

Comment: @JohanDonne Thanks for your suggestion, but this is not really in line with what I am looking for. One reason for sticking with the `new()` specialization is that it portable across platforms. Reflection, in particular against non-`public` methods, does not always play well on all platforms.

Comment: Is it a requirement that third parties be able to subclass `Foo`? If that is not a requirement then it is much easier to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Eric. Yes, my intention is that third parties should be able to subclass Foo.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inherit from class with private constructor only but you can make your empty constructor private and add constructor with property like **createdInsideFooFactory**. You should also remove **new()** constraint in your factory. This is a hack but will let developer know that instance should be created inside foo factory.

```
public class Foo
{
    private Foo()
    {
    }

    protected Foo(bool createdInsideFooFactory)
    {
        if (createdInsideFooFactory) return;

        throw new MyException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your statement that you cannot inherit from a class with a private constructor is false.  Can you figure out how to write a program that has a class with a private constructor and a derived class? There are at least two ways to do it.

Comment: @EricLippert: I can't, please enlighten us. The obvious ways I can think of are 1) provide an additional constructor that isn't private (but the answer specified "private constructor *only*", so that's cheating and 2) make the derived class a nested class (but that requires control over the definition of `Foo`, which is also cheating).

Comment: Yes only a private ctor. A nested class is the easy way. There's also a hard way.

Comment: Hint: does a derived class *have* to call a base class ctor?

Comment: @EricLippert: if we go by nothing but the C# language spec, then yes. It either calls a base class constructor (explicitly or implicitly) or another constructor of the same class, and loops (directly or indirectly) are prohibited, so that ultimately, a bcc must be called. Of course, at runtime you could avoid calling it through an exception, but that doesn't get around the declaration. Even if there was some hideous way to get this done, I'm pretty sure you'd necessarily end up with a class with no instances. Now spill the beans already, some of us didn't write the compiler. :-P

Comment: @AlexZaitsev, for several reasons, it is not an option for me to remove the `new()` constraint. What you have proposed will make it possible to define a subclass default constructor, that is correct, but I see no way to control whether or not that default constructor is called directly or via the factory? I.e., you can have `public Bar() : Foo(true)` or `public Bar() : Foo(false)`, but I see no way to control that this constructor is called either from the factory or directly.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Ah, the second technique has been removed. It used to be legal to have a loop in "this" constructor calls. That lets you get around calling the base ctor, which lets the program compile. Then you cause an exception in construction, catch the exception, and resurrect the object via a finalizer, and you have an instance of a derived class that never called a base class ctor.

Comment: @EricLippert: gee, of course, now I feel silly for not thinking of that. :-P The fact that you can resurrect partially constructed objects in finalizers is scary enough on its own, though. I can confirm that *that* still works quite "well".